# Need help, to understand the Browsercompabilitty

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser, w3c

I am kind of a newbee in big projects for webdevelopement and have to work on a website for my university. 
Therefore is one of the main-problems currently the browsercompatibility.
The internet explorer, safari and google chrome always implement some tables different. I put in the css a max width for the tables and it works for firefox and opera.

Therefore I have a few questions.
1.Is there a possibility for myself to put a standartisation on everything? 
2.Only in the Internetexplorer the tables are shown vertical insteadt of horizontal, how can this happen?

If anyone could at least have some answers for me, I would be extremely thankfull.

Greetings,
B0n0b0 ;3

Comment: Yes, you can, and it's very easy, but people prefer to write hacks and do extensive testing for pure job security. Please don't share it with outsiders, it's a guild secret! (If you have some specific problem with a specific browser, don't hesitate to ask here.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. :D
So the first thing ist: 
#content ol li, #content ul li{

    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    max-width: 13em;  }    
this is my css.
My tables are now in a line, without displacing.
Except in Google Chrome, there nothing changes :(

Comment: My excuses, when I said "ask here" I meant in [question format](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44129782/edit), so code is readable and you can even write a snippet to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To maximize browser compatibility some web-developers use a `CSS Reseter`. Its goal is to (kind of) standardize some CSS rules.

There are tons of CSS Reseters, you might want to search for one that suits your requirements.

See: [CSSReset](http://cssreset.com/) and [HTML5Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) for further information on this topic.

Comment: Thank you, big times! :3